# Pandas negative selection for string isin list gives wrong result

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring, series

According to other posts here this should bring back just two of the four domains

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Domain':['info.de','onfi.ru','kcast.fr','stack.cn']})

tld_1 =['.de', '.cn']
tld_2 =['info', 'stack']

df[~df['Domain'].isin(tld_1)]
df[~df['Domain'].isin(tld_2)]
```

but it brings back

```
 Domain
0   info.de
1   onfi.ru
2  kcast.fr
3  stack.cn
```

Any idea why and how I would properly select the domains containing the entries in the lists ?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.Series.isin` tests for membership, but you wish to test for substrings in strings.

You can do this via `pd.Series.str.contains` with regex, taking care to escape characters.

```
import re

regex1 = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in tld_1])
regex2 = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in tld_2])

res1 = df[df['Domain'].str.contains(regex1)]
res2 = df[df['Domain'].str.contains(regex2)]

print(len(res1.index))  # 2
print(len(res2.index))  # 2
```